# Set proxy for terminal in linux

Tags: linux, proxy, yum, centos7

In CentOS 7 how can i connect terminal through a "proxy with username and password" and use some command like:

```
yum update
```

For now when i use this command i got this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2a02:2498:1:3d:5054:ff:fed3:e91a: Network is unreachable"


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

    1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

    2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

    3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

    4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

Comment: Do you mean, assume an identity?  ``su [user]``, substitute user, for that.  Default user if not given, is *root*, which is likely what you'd want for ``yum update``.

Comment: I installed CentOS in VMWare,in my office we use proxy to connect to the internet. So i set that proxy in browser in CentOS and it works.But command in terminal can't connect to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yum uses HTTP so you need to set a http proxy for your environment.

Check this out: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-proxy-server.html

Answer (score 0):

try to run the command and you will be connected to do upload or whatever you want 
Just add : `dhclient` and press enter the this command : `yum update`